# Navigate from one datagrid to another on different pages

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have two pages (using NavigationWindow) in my application.
when i click on a row in my datagrid1 on page1 , is it possible to navigate to page 2 and populate the details in datagrid 2 on page2.

Answer (score 0):

Hi userXemY take a look at [eventaggregation](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) or shared viewmodels.

There are a lot of frameworks that use eventaggregation or some other form to communicate/navigate between views.

Like:

- [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator&referringTitle=Documentation)
- [Prism 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)
- [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/documentation) (i think)

Comment: I have not heard these before. thanks @jordy. currently I am developing my application on Visual studio, wpf application. is it possible to integrate these with VS ?

Comment: How do you mean integrate? and VS is Visual Studio? Are you trying to create an visual studio add-in?

Comment: VS is visual studio, i meant how can i use these frameworks in my current applications.

Comment: Most of them are just DLLs that you can reference in you application and then use the appropriate classes/interfaces that come with the frameworks.